# is it possible to open a web browser from my application without showing the URL?

Tags: android, android-layout

can somebody tell how to open a web browser from android app without showing url on the web browser. I don't want people to see url on the web browser which is opened via my app. your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: _I don't want people to see url..._ Why not? Your approach is definitely the wrong one if your concern is about security

Comment: You can not handle a WebBrowser its an another app . You can open the link inside your app in `WebView` .

Comment: @B001ᛦ No bad intention. I want to use that web page as part of my app. that's why

Comment: I wasn't talking about "bad intention" but "bad approach"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want show link to user - try to use WebView. This is the simpliest solution. 
You can't change browsers behaviour because it's other apps =( So you can't hide your link

Comment: _Please mark my answer like..._ This actually is not an answer and should have worked as comment....